# Access FULL JOIN for 7 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

How you doing?

I'm new in this SQL/Access world and I really need your wisdom, in order to do a simulated `FULL JOIN` in SQL-ACCESS or a best option to merge 7 tables.

I've tried with `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN + UNION` but didn't work out. These tables have only two values columns:

1. *ClientsID*
2. *PriceTypes* - different price types in the tables (Price1_tbl, Price2_tbl...Price7_tbl) that each could have a few common *ClientsID* in the 7 tables.

What I need as a result is:

1. To get a unique *ClientsID* column (of course not duplicated) appending every *ClientIDs* from these 7 tables;
2. And for the prices: the prices in the 7 tables in the 7 columns right the *ClientIDs*, matching if they match *ClientID* or with a `NULL` value if that table doesn't have that *ID* with a price.

Should be something like the print I've attached below:

[image: Example_with3_tables]

I put only 3 tables for the example. I know Access doesn't support `FULL JOIN`, I'm open to new ways to solve this issue.

I hope to be clear in my question,

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access

Comment: *I've tried with LEFT/RIGHT JOIN+UNION but didn't work out.* ... please post such efforts and any errors or undesired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate FULL OUTER JOIN with Access on more than two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700881/simulate-full-outer-join-with-access-on-more-than-two-tables)

Comment: if you read the post you can see is not the same Erik. it matches different tables. I tried to match 7 tables with an unique primary key, by the way is already done. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not available in MS Access and requires a `UNION ALL` of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, consider breaking apart the process into several queries. This avoids very nested subquery derived tables:

**Query 1** *(first two tables)*

```
SELECT a.ClientID, a.PRICE_A, b.PRICE_B
FROM ClientPriceA a LEFT JOIN ClientPriceB b
  ON a.CLIENTID = b.CLIENTID 
WHERE a.ID IS NOT NULL;

UNION ALL 

SELECT b.ClientID, a.PRICE_A, b.PRICE_B
FROM ClientPriceA a RIGHT JOIN ClientPriceB b
  ON a.CLIENTID = b.CLIENTID 
WHERE b.ID IS NOT NULL;
```

**Query 2** *(first two tables query + third table)   -- GENERATES POSTED DESIRED OUTPUT*

```
SELECT m.*
FROM 
  (SELECT f.ClientID, f.PRICE_A, f.PRICE_B, c.PRICE_C
   FROM Query1 f
   LEFT JOIN ClientPriceC c ON f.ClientiD = c.ClientID
   WHERE f.ClientID IS NOT NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c.ClientID, f.PRICE_A, f.PRICE_B, c.PRICE_C
   FROM Query1 f
   RIGHT JOIN ClientPriceC c ON f.ClientiD = c.ClientID
   WHERE c.ClientID IS NOT NULL
  )  AS m
ORDER BY m.ClientID;
```

Then repeat process for all others:

**Query 3** *(first three tables query + fourth table)*

```
...
```

**Query 4** *(first four tables query + fifth table)*

```
...
```

**Query 5** *(first five tables query + sixth table)*

```
...
```

**Query 6** *(first six tables query + seventh table)  --FINAL RESULT*

```
...
```

**NOTE**: You may run into an MS Access `UNION` limit or query too complex and so consider outputting queries into temp tables with make-table calls: `SELECT * INTO FROM (<query>)`.